# how can i install enable mcrypt without re-installing php?

Tags: php, mcrypt

I installed php 5.3.8 from source on Ubuntu 10.10 and now i need mcrypt. I also installed mcrypt from source and restarted apache but still i am not able to see it in my php configuration. I understand i would need a `mcrypt.so` in my php extensions directory.  I have installed a lot of extensions and like xdebug and apc and dont want to go through the pain of installing them again.
Now how can i install mcrypt without re-installing php and passing mcrypt as a parameter to configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually where you extracted the source you can find the source for all the modules as well. In this case, I think under the "ext" directory. 
So from the source folder:

```
[php-5.3.10]$ cd ext/mcrypt/
[mcrypt]$ phpize
[mcrypt]$ ./configure --your-options-here
[mcrypt]$ make && make install
```

Then edit your php.ini and add:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Finally, restart Apache.
And I *think* that should do it for you.

Comment: but this way i have to do the make and make install steps again. Cant i do it the way we install xdebug. i mean generating the `.so` file for mcrypt

Comment: If you run it in the directory I specified, "php-X.YY/ext/mcrypt" it will only build the Mcrypt sources, not all of PHP.The make and make install at the end then will only install the mcrypt.so file.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't feel comfortable running "make install", just run "make" and manually copy the .so file to the extensions directory, as shown by "php -i | grep extension_dir"

Comment: i have doing this make and make install and configure for some time but i dont understand the linux build process clearly. can u please forward me to some link which explains the build process clearly? thanks

Comment: This explains some of it - http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html - I haven't really seen a good explanation, but so far as I know what happens is "configure" will generate a MakeFile based on your system and its current layout. "Make" executes the default option in the MakeFile, which compiles everything and "make install" executes the "install" function, which (for the most part) just copies files to the correct place. If someone with more knowledge would like to shed additional light on this, please do. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cp /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php_old
```

Install php from source.

```
cp /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

make sure that this entry exists in this file `/etc/php.ini`

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

restart apache...

Comment: I think the point of the question was to not reinstall PHP, though that might not be really possible...